# Как отобразить белую круглую кнопку swift 4

Tags: swift, button

Мне нужно добавить кнопку, она белая и круглая
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я ее вставляю то получается вот это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть вокруг нее пиксели, я уже пробовал создавать и `image` и круглый `view` белого цвета.
И они тоже также отдают пикселями вокруг.
Как сделать круглую белую кнопку как на первом изображении?
Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у вас кривая картинка, проверьте кнопку в [визуальном дебаггере](https://youtu.be/Xx57T9MshBQ?t=28). Так же картинка может быть в слишком низком разрешении.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.height / 2
button.clipsToBounds = true
button.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: Делал точно так же 
Результат такой же

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял не получится сделать абсолютно белую кнопку на фоне который по цвету немного, да схож с цветом который ты хочешь сделать круглым
Заявления Nikita Zatsepilov что кривая картинка не подходят, так как я вставлял не картинку, а красил кнопку и `view` в белый цвет
Неужели нельзя в swift сделать такое?

Answer (score 0):

Я не профессионал, но для того, чтобы закруглилась кнопка, вместо использования button.frame.height в cornerRadius, как предложил @Vitaly, я бы использовал button.frame.width для этой цели